# window.close() and the beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I need to clear some session variables whenever user closes the browser window. The window can be closed in two ways:

- the normal way by pressing the window close button
- by pressing a custom button inside the window

I am using jQuery, so the listener is:

```
// clear some session variables
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    makeAjaxCall(some, params);
});
```

The window is closed by calling a function that eventually executes:

```
window.close();
```

The problem is that the second way to close the window only triggers the `beforeunload` event in FF. In Chrome the second way works only sometimes, in Safari it does not work at all. Any thoughts?

---

**SOLUTION** (so far):

```
// clear search filter whenever the user closes the window
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {   // most browsers except Safari
    doSomeMagic(param);
    return;
}).on('unload', function() {         // Chrome
    doSomeMagic(param);
});
```

This works in most browsers: IE8+, Chrome, FF when closing window with window.close() and/or native browser button

It also works in Safari if window is closed by native browser window.

Does not work in Opera at all.

Comment: onbeforeunload behaviour is not consistent across browser. Simple answer is you cannot set any logic based on this event except just make it returning a string to show a prompt dialog to user (even in FF, the custom message wouldn't be displayed). There was some workaround as setting ajax request to sync but chrome doesn't seem to like it and on recent chrome update, no more seems to work anyway

Comment: But how come it works by closing the window by pressing the X on window across all browsers? The problems only start when I need to use JS to close the window. Shouldn't window.close() trigger the `beforeunload` event? I event tried to manually trigger it and it worked in Chrome, but still no luck in Safari.

Comment: So why not instead of calling `window.close();`, call directly `makeAjaxCall()` and close window inside ajax request success callback or using promise method. But i'm still not convinced that closing the window using the native close button and then firing onbeforeunload event will work cross browser. I mean for sure the event is fired but onunload event of browser doesn't wait for onbeforeunload event to be completed before beeing called. So, you have no way to be sure the ajax request has completed

Comment: try this   $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
            alert("Bye now!");
        });

Comment: @DeadMoroz http://stackoverflow.com/a/21577501/1131841

Comment: have you tried to trigger this specific event manually? jQuery(window).trigger('beforeunload');

Comment: yes I did, ant it seems to work for most of the cases, but it's a bit of a nasty solution when you have to call standard event that should be triggered by window.close().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});

$(window).on('unload', function(){
     logout();

});
```

This solution works in all browsers and I have tested it.

Comment: Have you tested this in Safari?