# Invoke browser X button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dom-events

This question is brought up because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054134/how-to-close-the-browser-by-rejecting-popup-window-in-selenium-webdriver/29055017?noredirect=1#comment46347555_29055017). The problem is, probably, the page is designed to generate a confirmation alert only if the user click on browser **X** button. I know that `window.close()` will close the current browser window which *probably* is not the same as clicking the **X** of browser window. Is there any way, possibly with JavaScript to recreate the click action on browser **X** button as if a real user would do?

Comment: No there is not. `window.close()` will only work in child windows/tabs. You cannot close the parent browser window.

Comment: no thats dumb, what if someone is doing something important on another tab. What if you have a bunch of tabs open, and you visit a website that runs that code and closes all your window. You would be pissed. The only way would be a chrome extension or other browser extension.

Comment: [Run JavaScript code on window close](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13443562/4343318)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan @Edwin I know that. But, My question is, say only for current *tab*, what is the difference between clicking **X** and `window.close()`?

Comment: @callback Haven't tried. Going to. But what's the difference?

Comment: Assuming the tab is allowed to be closed programmatically by the browser, the difference is that `window.close()` would close the tab, whereas clicking X would close the entire browser program.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan then, there is no way to perform click **X** with `JavaScript`? I am aware that that should not be done. But, it's needed for testing purpose only

Comment: Correct, you cannot close the browser window with JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Appreciate your time

Comment: This may be the wrong question, if the intent is to offer the same confirmation dialog on either the browser's `onbeforeunload` event and/or whichever event (may be?) triggered by `window.close()`. I suspect since it's Javascript invoking the latter, the former is not invoked in a way where it's preventable (since it's not user-originating), so you don't get the dialog. Whatever is calling the `window.close()` should call the confirmation code directly before doing the close.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21577501/451969) suggests a solution that works on `window.close()` by using the `unload` event in addtion to `onbeforeunload`. The answeree claims it works in all browsers, but I presume Selenium was not tested. (Although looking at it, it may not work to prevent the close, if that's necessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.close()
```

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened
>   by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not
>   opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript
>   Console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script. *[Mozilla Developer Network: window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)*

So, there is not a way to close browser via javascript, but if you wan't to tigger some code that is supposed to be executed when window closes try this:

```
//plain js
window.onunload();

//plain js
window.onbeforeunload();

//jQuery
$(window).unload();
```

Or if you want to execute code when user tries to close window, try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   // Do something
}
// OR
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
   // Do something
}, false);

window.onunload = function(){
   // Do something
}
// OR
window.addEventListener("unload", function(e){
   // Do something
}, false);

// jQuery
$(window).unload(function(){
   // Do whatever you need
});
```

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be
>   ignored during this event. See the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#user-prompts) for more
>   details. *[MDN | window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)*

These events are fired in this order:

1. window.beforeunload (cancellable event)
2. window.pagehide
3. window.unload

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it was called by `window.open()` or at least something similar. Because `window.close()` closed the browser. But, If I perform click on **X** there is another pop up shows up to confirm the action which I do not get using `selenium`. I want to recreate the same with some kind of programming